# Access a nativeElement right after being pushed into ngFor loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm pushing a new item on a ngFor loop.
Right after I'm trying to get its html reference (ElementRef nativeElement).
But it's not "ready" yet. So I used a settimeout. Worked.

Is there any "elegant", angular way, solution instead of using settimeout?

I didn't post any code, because is a rather simple **array.push** and nativeElement use.

Comment: you can use ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: Well, the question is, why do you need the nativeElement? You have the data there already? Can probably be fixed in a more solid way but hard to tell without code.

Comment: @MikeOne I need it to apply "gestures" on the element. Specifically a longpress gesture. 
But I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the ChangeDetectorRef method: `detectChanges()`

right after the `.push()`
And worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngAfterViewInit() to get elements after the dom is loaded: https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

```js
ngAfterViewInit():void {
  this.elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
}
```